# Using .BY, .GRP or other methods to add a multicolumn aggregation with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Say we have this toy data.table example:

```
temp <- data.table(V=c("A", "B", "C", "D","A"), GR=c(1,1,1,2,2))    
"V" "GR"
 A   1
 B   1
 C   1
 D   2
 A   2
```

I would like to generate all ordered combinations with combn within each subset defined by GR and create with it a new data.table and with a new column with the grouping factor.

For example, for GR=1 we have (A,B),(A,C),(B,C)
for GR=2 we have (D,A)

If I create the result manually it would be

```
cbind(V=c(1,1,1,2),rbind(t(combn(c("A", "B", "C"),2)),t(combn(c( "D","A"),2))))

1  A  B
1  A  C
1  B  C
2  D  A
```

But I would like to do it with data.table easily instead.
This two option don't work:

```
temp[,cbind(rep(.GRP,.N),as.data.frame(t(combn(V,2)))),by=GR]     
temp[,cbind(rep(.BY,.N),as.data.frame(t(combn(V,2)))),by=GR]
```

This one work, but I don't understand why. I'm afraid it could copy the whole B vector as is instead of the proper value.

```
temp[,.(GR,as.list(as.data.frame((combn(V,2))))),by=GR]
```

And I guess it should be a shorter way to write it.

Comment: I  do not think you need `GR` twice in columns. `temp[(as.list(as.data.frame((combn(V,2))))),by=GR]   `

Comment: Error in ´[.data.table´(temp, (as.list(as.data.frame((combn(V, 2))))),  : 
  'by' or 'keyby' is supplied but not j

Comment: Sorry try this  `temp[,.(as.list(as.data.frame((combn(V,2))))),by=GR]  `

Comment: Oh, yes, anyway I said GR but I mean also more columns

Comment: Anyway it doesn't produce three columns, GR, V1 and V2 but only two, GR and V1, where V1 contains two elements separated by a comma.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have one solution but it seems long and complex too.

```
temp[,do.call(c, apply(t(combn(V,2)), 2, list)),by=GR]
```

I've also found that combn is 10 times slower than some specialized packages such as iterpc or combinat

```
temp[,do.call(c, apply(combn2(V), 2, list)),by=GR]
```

You must also first filter out any group having just one row because otherwise it would cause an error.

And this is my final version, much faster and needs much less memory:

```
temp[,.(from=rep(V,(.N-1):0),to=V[unlist(sapply(2:.N, seq, .N, simplify = T))]), by=GR]
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
> temp[, {v_comb = combn(V,2); .(v_comb[1,], v_comb[2,])}, by=GR]
   GR V1 V2
1:  1  A  B
2:  1  A  C
3:  1  B  C
4:  2  D  A
```

In general, I would avoid when possible all the reshaping operations within the data.table using `cbind()`, `rep()`, `as.data.frame()` or `t()`... It takes many trials-and-errors to figure out the right way to do it, and produces code that is very hard to maintain.

On the other hand, using code blocks `{...}` improves the readability of the code.

Answer (score 1):

This uses data.table, though not all within [] using .BY or .GRP.

```
library(data.table)
temp <- data.table(V=c("A", "B", "C", "D","A"), GR=c(1,1,1,2,2)) 

tempfunc <- function(x){ 
  dat <- as.data.table(t(combn(temp[GR == x, V], 2)))
  dat[, GR := x]
  setcolorder(dat, c("GR", "V1", "V2"))
  dat[]
}

rbindlist(lapply(unique(temp$GR), tempfunc))

   GR V1 V2
1:  1  A  B
2:  1  A  C
3:  1  B  C
4:  2  D  A
```

Comment: But I also need the GR as the first column

Comment: Added an assignment of the GR column within the function. Also set the column order using `setcolorder` in case GR needed to be the first column.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two other approaches which also work if there is a group with just one row, e.g., row 6 below:

```
library(data.table)
temp <- data.table(V=c("A", "B", "C", "D","A","E"), GR=c(1,1,1,2,2,3))    
temp
```

> ```
>    V GR
> 1: A  1
> 2: B  1
> 3: C  1
> 4: D  2
> 5: A  2
> 6: E  3
> ```

#### Using `cominat::combn2`

```
temp[, as.data.table(combinat::combn2(V)), by = GR]
```

> ```
>    GR V1 V2
> 1:  1  A  B
> 2:  1  A  C
> 3:  1  B  C
> 4:  2  D  A
> ```

#### Using a *non-equi join*

```
temp[, V := factor(V)][temp, on = .(GR, V < V), .(GR, x.V, i.V), 
                       nomatch = 0L, allow = TRUE]
```

> ```
>    GR x.V i.V
> 1:  1   A   B
> 2:  1   A   C
> 3:  1   B   C
> 4:  2   A   D
> ```